# fs.readFileSync in a template literal not working

Tags: typescript, node.js-fs

I'm trying to read a file with fs.readFileSync. When I put fs.readFileSync into a Template literal I get following Error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './cookie.txt'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:590:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:458:35)
    at new SteamgiftsBot (C:\Repositories\steamgifts-bot\src\steamgiftsBot.ts:15:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Repositories\steamgifts-bot\src\index.ts:3:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Repositories\steamgifts-bot\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Repositories\steamgifts-bot\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: './myfile.txt'
}
```

my current code (not working):

```js
    headers = {
        Cookie: `PHPSESSID=${fs.readFileSync("./cookie.txt", "utf-8")}`,
    };
```

my old code (working):

```js
    headers = {
    Cookie: "PHPSESSID=" + fs.readFileSync("./cookie.txt", "utf-8"),
  };
```

my commit:
https://github.com/butilka123/steamgifts-bot/commit/9ce373868d40aa21c94fe1e6e61b0c804dfe742a

I really don't know why its doing that and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The issue seems to have nothing to do with it being in a template literal. It's saying the file isn't found. Are you sure that the path is correct?

Comment: Yes it was working before.  ```test = "something=" + fs.readFileSync("./myfile.txt", "utf-8") ```

Comment: I edited the post with the old code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was:

```
headers = {
    Cookie: `PHPSESSID=${fs.readFileSync(
        path.resolve(__dirname, "./cookie.txt"),
    )}`,
}
```